# Dynamic update of DNS without the use of AD

Tags: dns, dhcp, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

I try to make a stand alone DNS and DHCP server without a domain controller. 
I have
[image: Client settings]

I have on the zone dk. enabled  "Nonsecure and secure"

Settings for DNS :
[image]

For DHCP I have checked "Enable DNS dynamic update according to the settings below"

So why is the DNS not updated with my client?

Comment: I see you are using VirtualBox, so you probably have your server in a virtual environment. Do you have the network set as bridged? otherwise, its not going to work because the VM is shielded from the rest of the network.

Comment: I use host-only network and I don't see why I need a network to the internet, I mean the zone is local and controlled by me. So local clients, here the host itself, should be registered.

Comment: Now I got the reverse lookup zone to work but not the forward zone. Do I need the "." in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by enabling "Always dynamically update DNS records"
But that is strange I thought 
"Dynamically update DNS records only if requested by the DHCP clients"

 would be sufficient. My client is a Windows 10
What makes a client request for DNS update.

Comment: Can you list your settings in both DHCP and DNS? I have the same issue in the same scenario but I can't make DNS dynamic update to work.